# Restrict page access with member login

Tags: security, authentication, password-protection

I need to make a completely normal restricted area of my website accessible only to registered, logged-in members. The restricted pages will be pulling data from a MySQL database using PHP.

I have been searching for a way to do this, finding many useless results. Most of what I've found is either insecure, outdated or just deals with one very specific area of the process. It is incredibly frustrating spending hours studying a method of doing this, only to find out that they've used some insecure method and it's completely useless. So I'm hoping to get the opinions of the experienced stackoverflow community to point me in the right direction.

So my question is this:
Knowing that hundreds of thousands of websites have exactly the same "register, log in, grant access to pages A, B and C, log out" combination of events, is there a universally accepted way of setting this up (and if not, why not)? Is this: http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL a "good" way of achieving this (assuming I figure out how to get it to work)?

The pages/database will not hold anything like credit card numbers or other sensitive information, so I don't think I'll have thousands of hackers constantly attacking the site, but I obviously want to maintain a reasonable level of security. I've been careful to avoid the potential of SQL injection attacks on the database side of things.

Many thanks,
Paul

Comment: I think the question is a bit too fuzzy to find good answers here. There are millions of ways to insecurely password protect a page, but also hundreds of thousands of ways to do so securely. No real direction to send you, except maybe to look at the [Open Web App Security Project](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page).

Answer (score 0):

try this.
**login.php**

```
<form action="check.php" method="post">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
<tr><td>Nickname:</td><td><input type="text" id="usernaame" name="usernaame"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Password:</td><td><input type="password" id="passworrd" name="passworrd"></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Login" class="button"></td></tr></table>
</form>
<br><a href="register.php"><button>Register</button></a></div>
```

**check.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$user = htmlspecialchars(addslashes($_POST['usernaame']));
//you can also edit password encryption
$password = htmlspecialchars(addslashes(md5(sha1($_POST['passworrd']))));
//put here your query
$query = mysqli_query();
if(mysqli_num_rows($query)=="1"){
$_SESSION['logged'] = $user;
}
else{echo 'Data is incorrect';}
?>
```

**index.php** (where protected content is)

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['logged'])){echo 'Please login';}
else{
//your private content here
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. But I've read that I shouldn't use SHA1 or MD5 for password encryption; I know you commented "you can also edit password encryption"...I don't know how to do this. It just seems bizarre that there isn't some kind of ready-made solution to this - it's such a standard thing that applies to so many websites. I'm sure of someone made a downloadable package and charged a couple of quid for it, they'd make a fortune.

Comment: You're right: infact, despite md5 and sha1 are commonly used, they can be hacked using brute force. Mine was just an example. You could use crypt function http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php

Comment: You should also salt the hashes.  (Explaining what that means is beyond the scope of this comment. :-) )

Comment: Holy cow, no ``crypt()``. For storing hashes of passwords, research PBKDF2.